# Highcharts multiple charts drilldown

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I have using couple of Highcharts as given below -

Now, when I click Female/Male on the gender chart, I would like to recreate the 'By Department' chart based on the gender selected.

Should I re-create the 'By Department' chart brand new or should I change the drilldown series of 'By department' chart'

[image]

Here is the gender chart code

populate_gender_chart = () => {

```
const filter_data = this.filter_data;
const setfilterstate = this.setfilterstate;
const populate_drilldown_data = this.populate_drilldown_data;

var options = {
  chart: {
    type: "pie",        
    events:{          
      drilldown: function(e){                                    
        var filter_by_value = (e.point.name === 'Female') ? 'F': 'M'                                      
         var series = populate_drilldown_data(e)            
          this.addSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series[0]);            


      },          
    },
  },




populate_department_name_chart = (data) => {
      const filter_data = this.filter_data;
      const setfilterstate = this.setfilterstate;
      var options = {
        chart: {
          type: "pie",        
          events:{          
            drilldown: function(e){                        
              console.log('department drilldown')
```

Wondering how to get the reference of the second chart when I drill down the first chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `drilldown` feature of Highchart.

For a basic setup, the `drilldown`series are defined in a separate array under the `drilldown`configuration. Each series configuration is given an id, which is used for the `drilldown`parent point to identify its series.

**API Reference:**

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/drilldown

https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-drilldown

**React Example of drilldown:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-ynf9i